# How to know which variables influence a Bayesian model

Tags: predictive-models, bayesian-network

Is there any way to know what variables in a predictive model are influencing the prediction result of a particular row in a dataset?

For example, I have a student dataset and my target variable is whether or not the student will evade school. My model predicted that student X has an 85% chance of leaving school. How do I know which of the variables are influencing the outcome for that particular student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what sort of model you're using.  I imagine that if your predictions are coming out as probabilities then you're using a logistic regression such as:

$Pr[\text{Student Evades School}|\vec{x}] = \frac{1}{1-\text{Exp}[\beta_0 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \beta_i x_i]}$

Where the $x_i$ are your predictor variables.

The simplest way to assess the relative predictive-ness of different $x_i$ is to consider the magnitude of the $\beta_i$.  When the coefficients are large, this means that small changes in the corresponding variable produce big changes in the predicted probability.  This would be a good approach if you wanted to, for example, find the variable that best reduced the probability of truancy.  Note that the sign of the $\beta_i$ reflects what an increase in $x_i$ will do to the probability; negative coefficients mean increasing the variable will decrease the probability.  Keep in mind that you will need to combine this information with the specific predictor variable values for a given predictor.  If $\beta_{10}$ is way bigger than every other $\beta_i$, but for specific prediction $x_{10} = 0$ then you will need to look for the next biggest $\beta_i$ and so on.

Comment: I'm using pomegranate API: [link](http://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html#prediction)
The topology of network is Naïve Bayes.

Do you have any examples of the technique you mentioned?

Comment: I don't think my answer applies then.  Nonparametric models are trickier when it comes to looking at the relative importance of covariates. 
 Fortunately because you're using a Naive Bayes network it should be fairly straightforward to analyze the conditional probability tables of your covariates, given a classification of your variable of interest (ie. $Pr[x_i|y]$).  If one of those is particularly "uneven" then that's a highl predictive variable because $Pr[y|x_i] \propto Pr[x_i|y]$.  Couldn't tell you what the quickest way to do that in pomegranate unfortuntately.

Comment: You might also "unit test" your model by comparing your predictions when you change only one covariate by one category value.  So if you have two covariates A and B that predict whether a student will evade, both taking values in $\{1,2\}$, then you might compare the prediction under $[A=1, B=1]$ to the prediction under $[A=2, B=1]$, etc.  This is not an ideal approach, IMO; it's a little ad hoc and for large numbers of covariates an exhaustive search is infeasible.  However if you only want to compare a small number of covariates to each other then it should work relatively well.